# Magento 2 extending product form hide fieldset

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent, magento-2.2.5, ui-form

I have extended product form functionality by using `product_form.xml` in the added fieldset. now I have to hide that fieldset on a particular condition, like on module disable.

I know about the `modifierPool` from there I can hide that field by putting a condition in.

**But is there any way to do it in XML like `dependsOnConfig` as we are using in menu.xml**?

Comment: have you try with `Dataprovider` ?

Comment: @ChiragPatel Yes i have tried with it.. but it can not give custom fieldset in array list. which i have declared in product_form.xml in my module